# Manipulate and process email

Tags: c#, gmail, pop3, thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird and I need to somehow manipulate and process the e-mails that are stored in inbox.msf file using C# language. In C# I am using SS2.Pop3 library.So, I was wondering, how do you parse an .msf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.msf files are mail summary files and do not contain emails (admittedly, it's been like 10 years since I looked). Thunderbird uses standard UNIX mbox formatted files to store mail.

There is only 1 parser for those files available in C# and that is [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) (which also happens to be my library).

I'm pretty sure that if you have an Inbox.msf file, right next to it should be a file called Inbox which has the actual mail in it. That's the file you want to parse.

Comment: Yes I have it. I found it. Thanks.I tried to use Outlook to connect my Pop account but I had some issues so I decided to do it with Thunderbird. I finally fixed the problem with Outlook, so I have the question is the procedure the same as with Thunderbird, and what do you think about Pop3.NET library

Comment: To parse local files, you don't need a POP3 library, you just need a message parser like MimeKit. But, if you are trying to connect to a POP3 server with some C# code to download mail, I would recommend my [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library as it is hands-down the best out there.